# How to: validate the existence of a database relationship in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a model `Product` that belongs to a `Trend`:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function trend()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Trend');
    }

}
```

And as part of my validation rules I would like to check that this relationship exists, and if not trigger an error using:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    ... some redirection code here
```

is called. I have tried to use the validation [exists](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists) like below, but it never fires.

```
$rules = array(
    'brand_name'  => 'required|min:3',
    'blurb'       => 'required',
    'link'        => 'required',
    'trend'       => 'exists:trends'
);
```

I have also tried a few variations on the `exists` method, but nothing ever seems to fire. I know that the instance I am testing on definitely *doesn't* have a relationship set.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I see now from typing this out that I am validating the *input* and not the models values. How would I actually validate a model instance's properties instead?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Laravel's built-in validation functionality. Your `exists:trends` just checks for the existence of the trend itself, not the relationship (which it doesn't know anything about).

Comment: Could you populate a hidden field in your form with the trend’s id value? You could then validate this against an integer rule.

Comment: Did you defined the association between product and trend?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo - yep I have it defined both ways

Comment: @duncmc good idea I will try that and report back

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the following code in a `ExchangeRate` class:

```
/**
 * Return the validator for this exchange rate.
 * 
 * @return Illuminate\Validation\Validator A validator instance.
 */
public function getValidator()
{
    $params = array(
        'from_currency_id' => $this->from_currency_id,
        'to_currency_id'   => $this->to_currency_id,
        'valid_from'       => $this->valid_from,
        'rate'             => $this->rate,
        'organization_id'  => $this->organization_id,
    );

    $rules = array(
        'from_currency_id' => ['required', 'exists:currencies,id'],
        'to_currency_id'   => ['required', 'exists:currencies,id', 'different:from_currency_id'],
        'valid_from'       => ['required', 'date'],
        'rate'             => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:0.0'],
        'organization_id'  => ['required', 'exists:organizations,id'],
    );

    return Validator::make($params, $rules);
}
```

Of course, this `ExchangeRate` class also have the associations defined:

```
public function from_currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Currency', 'from_currency_id');
}

public function to_currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Currency', 'to_currency_id');
}
```

And all this glued together works like a clock:

```
$validator = $exchangeRate->getValidator();

if ($validator->fails())
    throw new ValidationException($validator);
```

Comment: Let me know anything then.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of this and [this method](http://daylerees.com/trick-validation-within-models)